# Identity Serve 4 Token re-authentication

Tags: single-sign-on, identityserver4

I want to implement SSO using Identity server with multiple applications. I have authenticated one application user from identity server. I have a token. How can I re-authenticate the token(user and client) to get the access of web application 2 and 3 from identity server.

Comment: Please make sure you ask a question in the title

Answer (score 0):

Each application should get its own unique token (and be registered as separate clients in IdentityServer). When you try to access application #2, the user should already have a separate session cookie established with IdentityServer, so they do not need to authenticate again. They might need to give consent to the scopes the first time they access a new client.